# dojo toolkit 1.7.1: xhrget does not allow complete rendering of DataGrid in StackContainer?

Tags: datagrid, dojo, render, toolkit

I'm sure I've missed something somewhere since I'm new to using Dojo Toolkit and am looking for some more experienced hands to enlighten me.  I'm also new to stackoverflow so please bear with me as I learn the finer points of participating in this forum and getting the styling and formatting right...

I am attempting to load into the dojox.layout.ContentPanes inside a stackContainer
the html content and the associated Dojo modules and javascript to support a DataGrid and meeting with mixed success.  Using the declarative approach seems to work well enough but attempting to use the programmatic approach using xhrGet to load ContentPanes in a stackContainer is presenting some problems.  I prefer a programmatic method over declarative since it will allow in my opinion a more modular and maintainable design.  Since I am running into problems I have to think there must be another way that works and will accomplish what I'm trying to do in the way of keeping the html and javascript modular and maintainable.  I realize there is much more to establishing design constraints but this will have to do as a start.

I will provide some extracts of the code below and in followup but the overall design is to setup a single web page using boundary layout container which in turn holds a titlePane and stackContainer with contentPanes.  Using links running down the left side as a navigation panel I have hooked corresponding html pages that are in turn displayed inside corresponding contentPanes and are subsequently displayed on selecting the corresponding link with a click.  This works well to a point.  Declarative DataGrid tables embedded directly in the contentPane seem to render properly with data populating correctly populating the Grid and the Dojo style formatting selected such as claro or tundra and CSS styling seeming to work as would be expected.   However if I attempt to display a DataGrid programmatically by loading entirely thru xhrGet into the contentPane as a separate html page the html page content displays but it seems that Javascript, or Dojo modules are not activated and the DataGrid is partially displayed with its headers but none of the data gets populated.  CSS formatting does seem to be working to a limited degree but more research and assessment is needed to understand how much.

So at this point the programmatic approach that I'm using seems to work partially and I have not been able to get the DataGrid to populate or get a button to fire properly.  Maybe this is simply a Dojo limitation but I would have thought it to be fundamental use case that most use as their approach to organize and modularize their website implementations.  Hopefully some more experienced Dojo Toolkit users /developers can enlighten me on a better way or what I've missed.  As said before I'm happy to provide additional code snippets for the sake of clarity.  Here's a recap in outline form the issues:

Here's what IS working for me:
1. Using dijit.TitlePane I have a basic framework of menu of links running
down the left side which provide the navigation between the ContentPanes inside
the StackContainer.  Using href I am able to pull up a page inside the 
ContentPane with no problem.  Overall this works really well.
2. The content panes can display HTML formatted pages
3. Using a declarative approach statically generated DataGrids placed directly inside the designated contentPanes of the stackContainer render and properly populate with data since they are able to be referenced by the javascript of the main calling page since that page and the html where the DataGrids reside are the same.
4. Individual html pages containing javascript and dojo modules that can be displayed standalone and render and populate DataGrid properly.

Here's what is NOT working:
1. Javascript associated with the loaded html pages does not execute. 
2. DataGrid does not populate with data if html page is loaded into content
page with xhrGet.
3. Programmatic generation of DataGrids in ContentPanes do not display at all.

Some things I have tried to get the remote javascript to fire and dojo DataGrid to render:
1. setting up AttachEvent to dojox.layout.ContentPane with *container* and
execute scripts set to true in remote page.
2. use of connect
3. use of grid.resize grid.restart
4. use of stackcontainer.resize
5. xhrPost
6. dojo.parser.parse
7. specifying use of dojox.layout.ContentPane over dijit.layout.ContentPane

I'm not saying I've implemented these correctly only that I did make an attempt so if one of this options seems to be the way to correctly configure what I'm attempting to do then any detailed steps and key points are much appreciated.

Some associated questions:
1. What is the best approach to tracing the he location of a widget ID if 
it is called separate html page that is displayed inside a contentPane?
2. Is setContent a method that can be used to refresh a DataGrid?

Here's some snippets of the code to consider ... (I apologize in advance if the formatting is hard to read or missing I'm not sure if the HTML will load properly so may try in followup post):

Some Javascript that does the page loading (HTML farther Below):

```
       function loadContent(targetID) {
            var targetElement = targetID + ".html";
        dojo.xhrGet({
              url: targetElement,
              handleAs: "text",
              handle: function(response){
                   var node = dojo.byId(targetID).innerHTML;
                   dojo.byId(targetID).innerHTML = response;

                }
            });
            var selectedPane = dijit.byId("contentStack").selectChild(targetID);

         function trackLinkClick(targetID) {
              dojo.query("li *").onclick(function(evt){
                                dojo.stopEvent(evt);
                                var grid_box;
                                var targetID = evt.target.getAttribute("href").split("#")[1];
                                loadContent(targetID);

                            }
                    );
              return targetID;
         }
```

The HTML:

```
   `<body class="claro">`
   `<div id="preloader"></div>`
   `<div id="main" class="tpsMain dijitContainer dijitLayoutContainer"` 
   `dojoattachpoint="containerNode" dir="ltr" widgetid="main">`
   `<div id="dijit_layout_BorderContainer_0" class="dijitContainer` 
   `dijitBorderContainerNoGutter" lang="" gutters="true"` 
   `dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" dir="ltr"` 
   `widgetid="dijit_layout_BorderContainer_0" style="padding: 0px; left: 0px; top 0px; width: 1450px; height: 800px;">`
   `<div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Title</div>`
   `<div class="edgePanel" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title= "Content Panel" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">`
   `<div id= "contentStack" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.StackContainer"  data-dojo-id="contentStack" region= "center">`
   `<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id= "content_pane_1">First Set of Content</div>`
   `<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id= "content_pane_2">
```

Second Set of Content
`...`

`...`

`...`



`

....
...
I show only two contentPanes but in actually working code I have contentPanes for as many individual pages to be loaded.  Display of content and navigation to each corresponding contentPane works.

Hopefully a more experienced Dojo master will be able to help me find the flaws or come up with a better scheme to help me acheive what I'm setting out to do.  Hopefully I've provided enough detail and explanation.

Regards to all

Comment: Please note that I used dojox.layout.contentPane to hold the remote html page and that in the stackContainer the dijit.layout.contentPane are used.  It seems that dojox.layout.contentPane cannot be a child of a stackContainer and dojox.layout.contentPane has been id'd as the way to assign scripts to a specific contentPane using dojo/method.

Comment: for clarity's sake I forgot to include a brace in code above:

`            function loadContent(targetID) {
                var targetElement = targetID + ".html";
            dojo.xhrGet({
                  url: targetElement,
                  handleAs: "text",
                  handle: function(response){
                       var node = dojo.byId(targetID).innerHTML;
                       dojo.byId(targetID).innerHTML = response;
                        
                    }
                });
                var selectedPane = dijit.byId("contentStack").selectChild(targetID);
     }'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know dijit.layout.ContentPane does not parse the html to look for dijits / widgets in it. You might want to use dojox.layout.ContentPane instead, which calls the parser after loading ?

Comment: Thanks. good answer. I have indeed looked at this...but have not found success as of yet. the standalone page I have using uses dojox.layout.ContentPane and has no issues and I have attempted to rework all other places where a ContentPane is in the markup hierarchy...but the remote loading of the standalone page with xhrget fails.  To me having pages loaded remotely into ContentPanes seems to be an obvious use of Dojo.   Thanks again for the answer.  I need to do some more digging.

Comment: I don't think you should xhrGet the page then set content, but rather set the url of yourContentPane to the page you want to load. The the ContentPane will do the work of loading + parsing

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the reworking of the dojox.layout.ContentPanes at the top of the hierarchy. Still not seeing any results.   I have noticed that I can capture the click event that bubbles up with a function call in the index/main html page but the same function does not fire in the loaded html page.  I have also tried setting executescripts to true in various places but no luck. So still digging.

```
   '<div id= "contentStack" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.StackContainer"  data-dojo-id="contentStack" region= "center">'
   '<div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.ContentPane" id= "contentpane1">'
   'First Set of Test Content'
   '</div>'
   '<div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.ContentPane" id= "contentpane2">'
   'Second Set of Test Content'
    '</div>'
```